# Generating a table in word from rmarkdown using the flextable package error

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable

I have been trying to generate a table in R Markdown with output to word looking like this (a very common table format for chemical sciences):

[image]

I started with kable using markdown syntax to get the subscripts etc (eg. [FeBr~2~(dpbz)~2~]) which worked in the word document file. However, i could not modify the table design and most importantly i could not figure out how to get the headings to display properly. So i moved on using the flextable package. Here is my code so far (still work in progress):

````
```{r DipUVvis,echo=FALSE, anchor='Table S', tab.cap="Summary of catalytic reactions monitored with *in situ* UV-Vis spectroscopy."}
df<-data.frame(Entry=c('AMM 51^*a*^','AMM 52^*a*^','AMM 53^*a*^','AMM 54^*a*^','AMM 57^*b*^','AMM 58^*c*^','AMM 59^*d*^'),
           Precat=c('[FeBr~2~(dpbz)~2~] (4.00)','[FeBr~2~(dpbz)~2~] (2.00)','[FeBr~2~(dpbz)~2~] (1.00)','[FeBr~2~(dpbz)~2~] (0.50)','[FeBr~2~(dpbz)~2~] (2.00)','[FeBr(dpbz)~2~] (1.00)','[FeBr~2~(dpbz)~2~] (2.00)'),
           Nucl=c('Zn(4-tolyl)~2~/2 MgBr~2~ (100)','Zn(4-tolyl)~2~/2 MgBr~2~ (100)','Zn(4-tolyl)~2~/2 MgBr~2~ (100)','Zn(4-tolyl)~2~/2 MgBr~2~ (100)','Zn(4-tolyl)~2~/2 MgBr~2~ (100)','Zn(4-tolyl)~2~/2 MgBr~2~ (100)','Zn(4-tolyl)~2~/2 MgBr~2~ (100)'),
           BnBr=c(0,0,0,0,'42 + 42',42,42))

tbl<-regulartable(df)
tbl<-set_header_labels(tbl,Entry='Entry',Precat='Pre-catalyst (mM)',Nucl='Nucleophile (mM)',BnBr='BnBr (mM)')
tbl <- align( tbl, align = "center", part = "all" )
tbl<-autofit(tbl)
tbl
```
````

This took care of the headers and with a bit of setting the rest parameters i think i can get the table to look like in the picture above. The resulting table looks fine in the Rstudio console from a formatting perspective:

[image]

However, there are two major issues:

1) The subscripts/superscripts are not being translated.

2) When i Knit to word, instead of a table i get 5 pages of code, which from my understanding must be the html code?

After many hours of trying to sort this out, i found that one possible cause is R studio using an old version of pandoc (https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/34). Indeed that was the case for me so i changed it by moving the new installed files of pandoc in the correct directory (where r studio is looking) and renaming. This must have worked now (see second figure console section). However it didnt change anything. Then i tried adding in my code:

```
knit_print(tbl)
```

This keeps giving an error:

Error in knit_print.flextable(tbl) : `render_flextable` needs to be used as a renderer for a knitr/rmarkdown R code chunk (render by rmarkdown).

Interestingly, when i removed the last line from the r chunk in R studio (tbl) and added the following below the r chunk (not in it):

```
`r tbl`
```

The table was generated in word (of course i still didnt get the subscripts and superscripts right). It also had the Figure caption on the top and not the bottom as a desirable side effect of generating the table after the main r chunk.

Any ideas of what is going on and how can i get the correct table output in word? Really confused here, so thank you in advance for your help.

UPDATE: If i remove the `anchor = 'Table S'` from the chunk header the table comes out ok (still without the subscripts or superscripts though) but then i cant automatically number the tables (i have used this: https://gist.github.com/benmarwick/f3e0cafe668f3d6ff6e5 for autonumbering and cross referencing).

Comment: So, how did it go?